# Git switch between independent branches

Tags: git

I have two sets of code in my repository.  One is the old system, which from time to time I have to maintain.  The other is my new system.   I never want to merge the two, but I want to be able to switch between them.

Earlier I switched from the new branch to the original.  Today I want to go back to the feature branch, so I did this:

```
git switch feature/development
```

Then I try

```
git pull
```

and see various message about merges.

I also tried

```
git pull --force
```

and it says "Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files".

Is there a simple way to maintain both branches and switch back and forth between them?

Comment: Honestly if they're that different I'd clone to two separate local folders

Comment: Probably should have.  I thought "switch" was supposed to do everything for me. 
 And then each one can commit back to it's appropriate branch?

Comment: Also, this is BizTalk, so some of the files really can't be merged.

Answer (score 1):

The `git pull` command is a convenience command: it means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*.  The *second* command is selectable, but the default is `git merge`.

So you asked your Git to do a merge.  That merge *has not yet finished*.  You *must* finish or stop the merge before you can do anything else.

If you did not want to do a merge at all, use `git merge --abort` to stop the ongoing merge and put things back the way they were before you started a merge.  If you do want a merge, you must finish the merge operation for Git, which was not able to do this on its own, then use `git merge --continue` to tell Git that you have put the correct merge result into place and Git should save that as the correct result for future merges.

> Also, this is BizTalk, so some of the files really can't be merged.

Nonetheless, if you want to use `git merge`—which `git pull` will do—you *must* merge them, by constructing the correct result and telling Git that you have done so.  (Your other option is to not merge at all.)

> Is there a simple way to maintain both branches and switch back and forth between them?

Not if you use `git pull`, because that means *fetch and then merge*.  When you hit a merge conflict, you *must* fix it (or terminate the merge as shown above) before you can switch.<sup>1</sup>

If you just want to have two separate work-trees in which you work on two separate branches, consider:

- using `git worktree` if your Git is at least 2.15 (`git worktree` was new in Git 2.5 but there's a particularly bad bug that's not fixed until 2.15), or
- using two separate Git repositories.

With two separate work-trees—whether backed by two separate repositories, or a single shared one—you can leave merge conflicts in place as long as you like and still do work in the *other* work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are some minor exceptions to this rule but they don't apply in your case—if they did, your switch would have worked.

Comment: So after "git switch", is there anything else I need to do?  My .sln file didn't have the right projects in it, indicating that I hadn't done enough.

Comment: I'm on 2.25, I will read up on git worktree later today.  I had to force some things to continue my work today.

Comment: I'm not sure what your "force[d] things" did, so not sure what to advise at this point.

Comment: (And, yes, if you have `git switch` you have a new-enough Git to use `git worktree` too - `git switch` was first introduced in Git 2.23, where they split `git checkout` into two separate commands, finally.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [git stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

For example you have two branches, oldVersion and newVersion.
Actually you are working on oldVersion. Once you want to go on newVersion you can commit or stash if the job is not done.

Actually there is no pending changes so you can checkout to another branche easily.
When you will come back to oldVersion, you can retrieve your work from the stash with git pop.

Hope i have answer your question.

Comment: But I wanted to commit both regularly back to the repository.

Comment: Note that `git stash` does not work when you have unmerged files.